# R: find string of vector with as elements multiple string

Tags: r, string, vector

I want to search the word `"time"` in a vector that looks as follows: `c("last time","hello","bye bye")`

I want to return the position in the vector where the word "time" is found.

Comment: What do you want in return? Look at `?grep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` to do that:

```
vec <- c("last time","hello","bye bye")
grep("time", vec)
#[1] 1
```

It returns the index of where the string "time" was found in "vec" (here, the first element).

Another example:

```
grep("bye", vec)
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca use `grep` and regex with `\\b` (word boundary):

```
vec <- c("last time","hello","bye bye")
target <- "time"

pattern <- paste0("\\b", target, "\\b")
grep(pattern, vec)
# [1] 1
```